# How can I check Internet connectivity in a console?

Tags: command-line, networking, internet

Is there an easy way to check Internet connectivity from console? I am trying to play around in a shell script.
One idea I seem is to `wget --spider http://www.google.co.in/` and check the HTTP response code to interpret if the Internet connection is working fine. But I think there must be easy way without the need of checking a site that never crash ;)

**Edit:** Seems like there can be a lot of factors which can be individually examined, good thing. My intention at the moment is to check if my blog is down. I have setup cron to check it every minute.
For this, I am checking the HTTP response code of wget --spider to my blog. If its not 200, it notifies me (I believe this will be better than just pinging it, as the site may under be heavy load and may be timing out or respond very late). Now yesterday, there was some problem with my Internet. LAN was connected fine but just I couldn't access any site. So I keep on getting notifications as the script couldn't find 200 in the wget response. Now I want to make sure that it displays me notification when I do have internet connectivity.

So, checking for DNS and LAN connectivity is a bit overkill for me as I don't have that much specific need to figure out what problem it is. So what do you suggest how I do it?

Here is my script to keep checking downtime for my blog:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Sending the output of the wget in a variable and not what wget fetches
RESULT=`wget --spider http://blog.ashfame.com 2>&1`
FLAG=0

# Traverse the string considering it as an array of words
for x in $RESULT; do
    if [ "$x" = '200' ]; then
        FLAG=1 # This means all good
    fi
done

if [ $FLAG -eq '0' ]; then
    # A good point is to check if the internet is working or not
        # Check if we have internet connectivity by some other site
        RESULT=`wget --spider http://www.facebook.com 2>&1`
        for x in $RESULT; do
            if [ "$x" = '200' ]; then
                FLAG=1 # This means we do have internet connectivity and the blog is actually down
            fi
        done

    if [ $FLAG -eq '1' ]; then
        DISPLAY=:0 notify-send -t 2000 -i /home/ashfame/Dropbox/Ubuntu/icons/network-idle.png "Downtime Alert!" "http://blog.ashfame.com/ is down."         
    fi  
fi

exit
```

This way I need to check for internet connectivity only where there is an issue with my blog response code. Its a bit heavy (as I am not using ping) but should not give any false positives. Right? Also how can I randomize pinging to a different site everytime, like facebook, google, yahoo etc. Also (I was trying to avoid any I/O) I can write to a log file by which I can check the count of downtime checks and then skip further checks till the site is down or cause longer checks (10mins instead of every min). What do you think?

Comment: "Internet connectivity" does not have a clear definition, you can only test the connectivity to a specific service or set of services. If you mean "LAN" connectivity a good option is to ping your network gateway.

Comment: In layman terms, I would define Internet connectivity is if you can access internet. Problem can by anything in between. I just need to differentiate between if its working fine or there is problem out of the set of problem that can be responsible. I hope I made myself clear. :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Checking whether specific website is up

First, multiple good online monitoring services are available. To pick one, Pingdom includes free account for monitoring one target. (Disclaimer: I am *not* affiliated with Pingdom in any way).

Second, using `wget --spider` for your own script is a good idea. You'll get some false positives when your computer is down, or when your DNS server is not working. Checking the return code is straightforward way to do implement this:

```
wget --spider --quiet http://example.com
if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
  echo "Website failed!" | mail -s "Website down" your_email@provider.tld
fi
```

Yet again, there are shortcomings in this approach. If your provider has cached your DNS record, but the DNS server is down, others can't access your site even though monitoring says everything is fine. You can write short workaround with `host`, for example `host example.com <your dns server IP>`. That will return error if DNS server is not responding, even if OpenDNS or your own provider's DNS server works fine.

### Checking whether internet is working

There isn't really easy way to handle this in every case.

You can for example run `ping -c1` on multiple well known sites (for example www.google.com, facebook.com and ping.funet.fi) and check return codes to determine whether any destination is reachable. You can automatically check return code by using variable `$?`. Parameter `-c1` is limiting number of ping packets to one.

You may encounter problems with some public wifis when there is a login gateway that redirects all pings and HTTP requests. If so, you may get ping responses and non-error HTTP status codes, even when you can't access any other sites.

If you want to check cable state, you can use

```
sudo ethtool eth0
```

From output (excerpt):

```
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: Twisted Pair
Link detected: yes
```

However, this is not telling whether you really have connectivity or not, just whether cable is connected and *something* is on other end.

Comment: This is totally for my setup, working on Always-ON Ethernet. But glad that you pointed out how it won't work correctly in some cases. Also I believe pinging would be faster than wget. What do you think? and if I am checking for a 200 status code anywhere, I would rather be just pinging it. Right? or there is something that I should know?

Comment: ping is faster, and better, because other end won't be angry for you. ping is pretty safe, but even that do not guarantee that you can open web pages. Also, it is *possible* that firewall is blocking ping but allowing HTTP requests.

Comment: Pinging a well known dns server like 4.2.2.2 is also useful in case you have net connectivity but broken dns.

Comment: For DNS checking you can of course use `host` (DNS query). It's very fast also.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Olli & @djeikyb I have updated the question, please take a look

Comment: @Ashfame: I also updated my answer to answer to your updated question.

Comment: @Olli Please take a look at the script in the question

Comment: Easier than checking return code, you can just use `if ! wget --spider http://example.com ...`

Comment: The silent mode is advised. So please use `wget -q --spider http://example.com`. And check the output `if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Online"
else
    echo "Offline"
fi`

Comment: @danger89 good point, added `--quiet`. The example is already checking the return code with `!= 0`, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 14):

I just used

```
nm-online
```

which pauses until a network connection is present by network manager. Worked well. You can do other stuff with it too.

Comment: nm-online requires network-manager package which is not installed by default in ubunto server but installed in ubunto desktop

Answer (score 9):

I'm using this method...

```
if [[ "$(ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | grep '100% packet loss' )" != "" ]]; then
    echo "Internet isn't present"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Internet is present"
    wget www.site.com
fi
```

Comment: I got different results for `ping -c 1 8.8.8.8` and `ping -c 1 www.google.com`. How is that?

Comment: Note that this will fail in China and other countries that block Google

Answer (score 8):

Checking to see if a site is up is usually done with a monitoring tool like `nagios`.  This will continuously monitor the site, and can notify you of outages.

When checking if the Internet is up from the command line I run through a number of steps:

- Check Internet is up `ping google.com` (checks DNS and known reachable site).
- Check web site is up use `wget` or `w3m` to fetch page.

If Internet is not up diagnose outward.

- Check gateway is pingable. (Check ifconfig for gateway address.)
- Check DNS servers are pingable. (Check /etc/resolv.conf for addresses.)
- Check to see if firewall is blocking. (Check /var/log/syslog as I log blocks.)

If Internet is up but site is down check with `w3m http://isup.me/example.com` replacing `example.com` with the site that appears down.  Use wget, lynx, or which ever command line browser you have available if you don't have the w3m browser installed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Does my script covers the basic requirement of checking and alerting me when my site is down? And it will be quiet in case there is some Internet connectivity problem

Comment: It looks like your script will do what you want.  You could include the wget command in the if statement as `if ! wget --spider http:///example.com; then`.

Comment: you mean wget always return 1 for 200 HTTP response code?

Comment: I mean the test `[ $? != 0 ]` is the the same as the test `! command`.  wget is documented to return 0 on success and not 0 for failure.  The if behaves identically which ever way you code it.  If wget returns failure on a 200 response, the test will fail either way your write it.  The same if it returns 0 for a response code other than 200.

Comment: Thanks! That would make the script smaller and easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

This is the shell srcript I'm using to test for internet connectivity:

alarm.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

if curl --silent --head http://www.google.com/ |
    egrep "20[0-9] Found|30[0-9] Found" >/dev/null
then
    echo Internet status: OK
else
    echo Internet status: ERROR
    mpg321 alarm.mp3 &> /dev/null
fi
sleep 60
clear

./alarm.sh
```

You will need to install curl and mpg321

```
sudo apt-get install curl mpg321
```

You will need a .mp3 sound file renamed to alarm.mp3 in the same folder if you want audible alarm functionality. Finally configure website URL and egrep to your needs.

Comment: This works perfectly even when the user is behind a captive portal and has not logged in.

Comment: You can use `egrep -q` instead of `egrep ... > /dev/null`

Comment: Why does the script call itself instead of just using a `while` loop?

Comment: Oh wait, it doesn't call itself. It calls a script called `alarm.sh` in the wd, so if you call this script from a different dir, it will either error, or if there's a script called `alarm.sh` in the wd, it will call that instead. So that's bad practice. You could use `"$0"` instead, but a `while` loop would be better.

Comment: "Why does the script call itself instead of just using a while loop? " : Because I was a noobs when I made that post and yes that script was calling itself.

Answer (score 4):

I am using this method:

```
if curl -s --head  --request GET www.google.com | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null ; then
    echo "Internet is present"
else
    echo "Internet isn't present"
fi
```

It will try to connect to a well-known website and if it can connect to it then we will assume there is the internet.

Answer (score 3):

### Checking whether internet is working

```
sudo nm-tool | grep "State: connected" | wc -l
```

From output (excerpt):

```
1 #System is connected to internet
```

However, as mentioned by others, this is not telling whether you really have connectivity or not. Eg. You could be connected to the router and router is not necessarily connected to internet.

Comment: `nm-tool` has been removed in Ubuntu 15.04+, but you can use `nmcli` instead. E.g. `[[ $(nmcli -f STATE -t g) = connected ]]`

Comment: @Six `nmcli -f STATE -t nm` the good thing is being independent of web sites!

Comment: Note that `nm-tool` and `nmcli` will tell you only whether or not you're connected to *local* network, i.e. whether or not you're connected to your home wifi/ethernet.  It won't tell you whether or not you can reach anything beyond your local network, i.e. internet.

Answer (score 0):

I needed help with the same question, and I got my answer this way:

```
echo $(nm-online) $? connection problems
```

Comment: how does this work?

Comment: It is just checking the status (one character) of the `nm-online` command... It will return 0 if everything is fine. Usual in all `UNIX` shells.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a script that would continuously test my internet connection, that would be started whenever my server was up and I made this:

1. First, install fping

   ```
   apt-get install fping
   ```
2. Create an init script in the /etc/init.d folder with the following content (I called it testcon)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   PIDFILE=/var/run/testcon.pid

   . /lib/lsb/init-functions

   case "$1" in
     start)
           log_daemon_msg "Starting internet connection tester"
           /etc/init.d/testcond &
           echo $! > $PIDFILE
           log_end_msg $?
       ;;
     stop)
           log_daemon_msg "Stopping internet connection tester"
           PID=$(cat $PIDFILE)
           kill -9 "$PID"
           log_end_msg $?
       ;;
     *)
       echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/testcon {start|stop}"
       exit 1
       ;;
   esac

   exit 0
   ```
3. Create a script in the /etc/init.d folder with the following content (I called it testcond)

   ```
   #echo Computer starting or testing daemon init
   while [ "$itest" == "" ] 
   do
       #wait 5 seconds 
       sleep 5
       itest=$(fping 8.8.8.8 | grep alive)
   done
   date | mail -s "Server is up and Internet is online" your_email@gmail.com

   #loop forever
   while [ "1" == "1" ] 
   do
       itest=$(fping 8.8.8.8 | grep alive)
       #if internet is down
       if [ "$itest" == "" ] 
       then
           #echo Internet is down
           #log time it was found down
           current_time=$(date)
           echo "Internet was found down @ $current_time" >> /mnt/data/Server/internet_log.txt
           #loop until it is back
           while [ "$itest" == "" ] 
           do
               #wait 60 seconds 
               sleep 60
               itest=$(fping 8.8.8.8 | grep alive) # test the internet
           done
           #when it is back
           current_time=$(date)
           echo "Internet is back        @ $current_time" >> /mnt/data/Server/internet_log.txt
           body=$(tail -2 /mnt/data/Server/internet_log.txt)
           echo "$body" | mail -s "Internet is back online" your_email@gmail.com
       fi
       #echo Internet is online
       #wait 60 seconds
       sleep 60
           done
   ```
4. Then I run the commands below to add to the start-up:

   ```
   sudo update-rc.d testcon defaults
   sudo update-rc.d testcon enable
   ```
5. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

Checking whether Internet is working is not so trivial. ping is ICMP, so it might work even if the web proxy is down. Something similar occurs with DNS if you test with an IP.

Since my Internet connection is unstable I created this script ([based on this one](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2009/04/02/tiny-bash-scripts-check-internet-connection-availability/)) that makes a gentle chord sound to call me, and also uses Ubuntu notify when the Internet connection comes back:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

hash play 2>&- || { echo >&2 "I require «play» but it's not installed. Try apt-get install sox. Aborting."; exit 1; }

WGET="`which wget`"
URL="http://www.google.com"
delay=3;
noConnectionMessage="No connection, trying again in $delay seconds...";
connectionMessage="WE HAVE INTERNET! :) Trying again in $delay seconds...";

echo "INTERNET TESTER: Type Ctrl+C to quit";
rm --force /tmp/index.site

function playSound {
    time=1;    # Time played
    if [ `sox --version| grep -oP "v[0-9.]+" | sed "s/[v.]//g"` -lt 1431 ]; then    #analize sox version, if greater than v14.3.1 can use pluck
        play -q -n synth $time sine;
    else
        play -q -n synth $time pluck $1;
        #for i in G4 G4 G4 E4;do play -n synth 0.1 pluck $i repeat 2;done    # You can play with something like this also :) (first three notes from Beethoven 5th symphony)
    fi
}

while [ 1 -eq 1 ]; do
    $WGET -q --tries=10 --timeout=2 $URL -O /tmp/index.site &> /dev/null
    if [ ! -s /tmp/index.site ];then
        echo $noConnectionMessage;
        #playSound E2
        sleep 1;
    else
        #~ zenity --warning --text "ADDRESS is back"
        notify-send -i "notification-network-wireless-full" "Connection state:" "$connectionMessage";
        echo $connectionMessage;
        playSound E3
    fi
    sleep $delay;
done

exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with random droppings of Wi-Fi connections by my `Broadcom BCM94331CD` chip. I devised the following bash script (infinite loop) checking each second if the Internet Wi-Fi connection is up and running. Other command line proposed here will wait for at least 5 to 10 seconds before closing with a status i.e. `ping`. In the mean time I am looking for a definitive solution as well.

From results on askubuntu, I will have to purge the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package as I use `firmware-b43-installer` and `b43-fwcutter`.

Thanks everyone for their suggestions (above).

This script needs to be added in the Start-Up Programs and don't need `super user` privilege to run as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

# Check if Wi-Fi is disabled e.g. 'out of range'
# If so quickly re-enable Wi-Fi
# Due to a problem with Broadcom proprietary driver in package firmware-b43-installer

# Script is part of Start-Up programs
# Stored in /usr/local/bin/
# Infinite loop checking every second if Wi-Fi is up and running

while true; do
  # https://askubuntu.com/questions/27954/how-can-i-check-internet-connectivity-in-a-console
  if [[ $(nmcli -f STATE -t g) != 'connected' ]]; then
    # Disable and Re-Enable Wi-Fi as the Wi-Fi is now 'out of range' (disconnected)
    nmcli radio wifi off
    nmcli radio wifi on
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading this but I see no mention on using monit to check the same.

In monit, the principle of ping is applied when you set something like this in monitrc file:

```
check host OnlineStatus with address 1.1.1.1
```

I used CloudFlare 1.1.1.1, but of course you can use domain or other ip as prescribed in [monit website](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#CONNECTION-TESTS) and [its wiki](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples). You then can set what it should do if that ping failed, for instance:

```
   if failed icmp type echo count 3 with timeout 10 seconds then exec "command-or- script"
```

Whether this is to check your server is online (connected to the internet) or certain services like web or mail server are still working or even restart them if they failed, warning you via email, you can rely on monit, that is if you installed in your server and configured it accordingly.

Comment: How do you then get the monit result from the command line?

Comment: @muru Monit is a monitoring tool where status for "things" that you are monitoring can be viewed using its very command `monit status` or via its page on default port 2812, if you run a web server, or if you set it to execute certain command or script to give you your desired result, or send email to alert you in case of failure.

Comment: Then please include an example of using `monit status` to check internet activity using the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you need for you script or alias oneline command to check Internet connectivity on Linux or macOS, you can use this:

```bash
[ $(wget --quiet --spider https://google.com &>/dev/null; echo $?) -ne 0 ] && echo "No Internet" && exit
```

adapted from: [9 commands to check if connected to internet with shell script examples | GoLinuxCloud](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/commands-check-if-connected-to-internet-shell/#How_To_check_if_connected_to_internet_using_shell_script)