# watch internet connection through shell

Tags: internet, scripts, ping

I just need to run a shell script when an internet connection is available. Is it possible to watch the internet connection availability through shell scripting?

`ping google.com` is the easy command to get it working. But how can I watch it?

Comment: Wired? WIFI? Is this a case of if the connection is up, you're connected, or a hard-wired eth0 with flaky internet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check Internet connectivity in a console?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27954/how-can-i-check-internet-connectivity-in-a-console)

Comment: @MarkWilliams any of it

Answer (score 2):

I think you might just be looking for

```
ping -c1 -W1 google.com >/dev/null && command
```

That will execute `command` only if the ping was successful.

Answer (score 0):

If watching means looking at transfer speeds, I have two solutions.

#### Speed of interfaces(wifi, ethernet)

`ifstat -S`

#### Speed of individual transfers/connections

`sudo iftop`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]; do
   TEST=$(nmcli -f STATE dev status | awk '/connected/ {print 1}')
    if [ $TEST ]; then
      # place whatever you wanna do here if connection is available
    fi
sleep 0.25
done
```

`nmcli` has command `dev status` that shows the status of network interfaces. So, we check only the status column of the output with the `-f STATUS` format flag. If we have connection, regardless if that's ethernet or wifi, we set TEST variable to 1 , meaning true. Next is `if . . then . . .fi` statement, which actually does the job.