# Suddenly the Wi-Fi Broadcom 5 GHz interface is shown 'Out of Range' permanently

Tags: networking, network-manager, broadcom

For several days since install I had my Broacom Wi-Fi working flawlessly on both interfaces, 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz. To install it I had to install 2 packages `firmware-b43-installer` and `b43-fwcutter`. However following a prolonged DNS server failure, the 5 GHz interface is shown permanently as `Out of Range` and unusable.

[image]

Although `Mac OS` and `Windows` still have no problem using it, right on the same hardware in multi-boot... So it's definitely a configuration failure in Ubuntu.

I did a full removal, purging the 2 packages and re-installing them to no avail. For instance right after the original install I could see some brcmwl hardware while checking for `hard blocked`:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
$
```

Right after the trouble appeared and as well after full re-install of the 2 packages I have only:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
$
```

As `brcmwl-0` disappeared completely.

As well the following command list only the 2.4 GHz interface:

```
$ iwconfig
wlp5s0b1  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Linksys37528"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: B4:75:0E:F8:C4:36   
          Bit Rate=36 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:13  Invalid misc:99   Missed beacon:0
$
```

It looks like it's disabled somewhere. But how to fully enable all Wi-Fi interfaces in Ubuntu ? Something is garbled somewhere.

Running the`Wireless Info Script` suggested by this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) from Ask Ubuntu, and posted [online](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SzJPSPdxcC/) here, just list the 14 2.4 GHz channel frequencies on `wlp5s0b1` interface. However no `wlp5s0b0` or `wlp5s0b2` is found, and this is the real problem.

One excerpt shows troubling info. as well regarding the 5GHz interface:

```
##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Linksys37528 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Linksys37528 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp5s0b1' [IF6]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Linksys37528
[ipv4] method=manual
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Linksys37528]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Linksys37528 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Linksys37528
[ipv4] method=manual
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Linksys37528_5GHz 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Linksys37528_5GHz 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp5s0b1' [IF6]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Linksys37528_5GHz
[ipv4] method=manual
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Linksys37528_5GHz]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Linksys37528_5GHz | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Linksys37528_5GHz
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto
```

As the `[ipv4] method=auto` is dead false. It is like on the 2.4 GHz set to `manual`. I did set it another time to `manual` , but still the profile won't budge to `auto` here. Although when checking in System Settings it is definitely set as `manual` addressing.

Where can I find the appropriate support in Ubuntu to fix this troubling network adapter configuration ? There seems to be close to none support about it.

Comment: "However no wlp5s0b0 or wlp5s0b2 is found, and this is the real problem." It doesn't work that way. Either your wireless interface wlp5s0b1 does 2.4 gHz and 5 gHz or it does not. I'm studying. More later.

Comment: What is the result of: `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | grep Status` ?

Comment: As I said before I didn't install this package as it did not support my `Broadcom BCM94331CD`. So the result is package is not installed and no information is available.

Comment: So, you already tried it and it didn't work? I suspect you had it in place at some point because of this: "brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN" in rfkill. There are at least four things we could try, all experimentally, and bcmwl-kernel-source is the first. Shall I propose an answer here or is this easier to do in chat?

Comment: May be it's easier in chat. May be you didn't get it right. The package `bcmwl-kernel-source` won't work for my adapter.  $ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
I suggest you read https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/38821 about it. It was working on the initial install and I kept the result in a text file. That is what I've posted here. But after the incident, it never showed up.

Comment: I read that link really well. Did you note this? "Huge Thanks to Chili555 really. This guy knows his stuff" Please join me in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74176/chat-with-antonio-and-chili555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up re-installing package `bcmwl-kernel-source` as `chili555` told me. Thanks for his suggestion.

`[Side NOTE]:` `bcmwl-kernel-source` was first installed, because I used another network adapter which was working well with it on both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz. Then when I switched to a new network adapter I did install package `firmware-b43-installer` as it was required by the documentation available. Later I did uninstall `bcmwl-kernel-source` to avoid connection droppings.

The reason why is that installing the package `bcmwl-kernel-source` will allow Ubuntu to see the 5 GHz Wi-Fi Interface.

The trouble is that with both packages `bcmwl-kernel-source` and `firmware-b43-installer` installed, the Wi-Fi connection is dropped randomly (several times per hour at times). There might be some concurrent activity behind, a race condition between the 2 ?

It should be noted that from [this reference answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/38821), only `firmware-b43-installer` is required. as the PCI id is:

```
$ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
$
```

Then in the BROADCOM WIRELESS TABLE (Updated Aug 18, 2017), I found this entry:

```
14e4:4331           firmware-b43-installer            firmware-b43-installer
```

Giving the package to install in `Xenial 16.04 LTS` and `17.10+`.

Uninstalling `bcmwl-kernel-source` will stop the connection drops, however, from my experience, if there is a problem on the connection like a DNS Server down, you can loose the 5 GHz interface altogether as shown in the question itself.

It's a shame that we are not getting a fully working driver solution from Broadcom. This network adapter works flawlessly on 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz in Windows and Mac OS X. It looks like the working package `firmware-b43-installer` is old enough not to support the 5 GHz interface ?

[Another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772528/wifi-dropping-at-random-times-bcm43142) has already suggested the removal of package `bcmwl-kernel-source` to avoid the connection dropping randomly. However, at least one user found this solution not functional as well.

In the mean time I wrote a quick bash script named `check-for-wi-fi-up-and-runnig` to restore the Wi-Fi connection as soon as it's disconnected:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

# Check if Wi-Fi is disabled e.g. 'out of range'
# If so quickly re-enable Wi-Fi
# Due to a problem with Broadcom proprietary driver in package firmware-b43-installer

# Script is part of Start-Up programs
# Stored in /usr/local/bin/
# Infinite loop checking every second if Wi-Fi is up and running

while true; do
  # https://askubuntu.com/questions/27954/how-can-i-check-internet-connectivity-in-a-console
  if [[ $(nmcli -f STATE -t g) != 'connected' ]]; then
    # Disable and Re-Enable Wi-Fi as the Wi-Fi is now 'out of range' (disconnected)
    nmcli radio wifi off
    sleep 3
    nmcli radio wifi on
    sleep 120
  fi
  sleep 1
done
```

May be I can throttled down `sleep 3` to `sleep 1`, pending further testing.

So basically, right now it is a trade off between no connection dropping, but having to re-install a driver package at times or an unstable connection with several drops per hour at times ...